How does やがる work with the intransitive?

打ち合わせが済んでやがる

Recently I meet this sentence. The character... is complaining his group of friends and disagreeing on what they want to do. In the end he loses the discussions and shouts this:
"打ち合わせが済んでやがる"
How does でやがる work with an intransitive sentence?

Do you mean you believe やがる is only for transitive verbs? Why?

I'd read that as the speaker saying the others made agreement beforehand (behind him).

@naruto isn't it used akin to "How dare you do x/having the nerve to do x"?

If that's what you're asking, the title of your question should be "やがる with an inanimate subject", not "やがる with an intransitive verb". An intransitive verb refers to a verb that does not take a direct object (寝る, 走る, etc), but there's nothing wrong with あいつは寝やがった, right?

"やがる" is a slang use by male
to express disgust toward the action caused by the subjective.
It is common to hear from anime naratives or yakuza movies.
I think it sounds kinda "ちんぴら"-ish that people avoid talk that way in real life.
"打ち合わせが済んでる" = "they've coordinated their stories."
"打ち合わせが済んで" + "やがる" = "they made up the bullshit story."
【Ｎ０文法】～やがる
